# How to filter requests on Delphi datasnap rest server?

Tags: delphi, rest, http, authentication, datasnap

I'm new to this delphi datasnap stuff and there are barely any useful documentations about it.

I've setup a simple rest server by following [this guide](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41305). Now I want to define my own authentication protocol.

As far as I know. All requests came from remote clients will be processed through WebModule methods before invoking server class methods. So far, I was able to capture the client IP adress  and the requesting URL path like this:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
ShowMessage(request.RemoteAddr); // adress where request came from
ShowMessage(request.PathInfo); // url path
  Response.SetCustomHeader('access-control-allow-origin','*');
  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

How am I able to:

Reject requests depend on specific IP addresses and return 401 status code to clients before they reach the class methods?

Redirect client to another methods? For example: Redirect this resquest:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/blah', true);
```

To another method instead of ReverseString.

Comment: You added a CORS header (access-control-allow-origin) to the HTTP response. It would be interesting to know if this works as expected, allowing cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

Complex redirection scenarios can be handled with an Apache HTTP server as reverse proxy with the mod_rewrite module.

For example, this answer shows that client IP addresses can be used to trigger a redirection.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073877/80901

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.0\.1\.1$
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.html
```

this would send all requests with some exception to a maintenance page.

Using Apache (or a different HTTP proxy server) also allows to keep the DataSnap server running continuously, while Apache configuration changes are applied. This will remove your server down time virtually to zero.