# Different Apache Configurations based on Requestors IP

Tags: apache, apache-config

I'm wondering if there is a way to use some kind of if-else construct within an apache httpd 2.2 config.

The idea behind this is this: I want to use www.domain.com for two different liferay installations (for a limited time). I want some specific requestors (identified via ip) to see my new setup so they can start writing some content but the rest of the world should still see my old liferay.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.11.12.13:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com

    IF_SPECIFIED_IP_THEN
        some new settings
        ...
        mount my new liferay
    ELSE
        old settings
        ....
        mount my old liferay
    END_IF
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know if something like this is possible. So I'd be thankful for any knowledge that you'd be willing to share.

Thanks in advance guys and regards. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mounts dynamically won't work. Set up the 2 system on different paths and use [mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073852/mod-rewrite-based-on-ip) to change the request