# htaccess image restriction is working perfectly on all domain and also working my local host but not working http://192.168.4.2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file contents:
The file is clipped for brevity.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://192.168.4.2 [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http://192.168.4.2 [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ - [F]
```

The idea is that the `jpg` extension is forbidden (using the [F|forbidden](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) flag).

This works fine in all environments except for my IP at `http://192.168.4.2`.
Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Avoid capitals. Format your question better. Add your code (what you have tried) so that it can be recreated and clearly explain the problem/question you seek help for. Please review the help section (https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be because the pattern string in your `RewriteCond` uses a full URL (`http://localhost/vpn`) instead of a relative one (`/vpn`). You may want to try this -

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^/vpn [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/vpn [NC]
    RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i am sorry now my code changed.please help me in this url 192.168.4.2

Comment: What exactly changed in your code? Just the IP address? Or the URL structure as well?

Comment: yes i only changed my url problem in this url please help me

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on your change in the question's details -
You will have to change your `RewriteCond` as follows.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.4\.2$ 
RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ - [F]
```

Use the condition `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` instead of `%{HTTP_REFERER}`

Possible Duplicate of - [mod_rewrite based on ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073852/mod-rewrite-based-on-ip)

Comment: Why have you posted _two_ answers...? Could they not have been concatenated? Is one redundant?

Comment: The OP has changed the original description of his/her problem. The first answer was posted for the original description before this change was made.

Comment: Then I'd wager that you should probably delete that question if it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google and read of the documentation led me to this link:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images

Try changing your code to this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}"  "!^$"                      # no referer (they entered the URL directly)
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFERER}"  "!http://192.168.4.2" [NC] # they came from an address at "www.example.com"
RewriteRule "\.(gif|jpg|png)$" "-" [F,NC]                 # the extension to block, separated by a pipe ("|")
```

A few notes:

- Removed the pointless `RewriteCond` (`!^http://192.168.4.2`).
  The caret symbol is from RegEx and is used to denote the start of a pattern. This meant that both of your rules are practically the same.
- Added a blank referer pattern.
- Added other extensions.
  This is from the documentation and the extensions you block are up to you.
- Added some comments to explain.